# Font in 'About' dialog in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am currently using Ecplise RCP to develop a small application.

My question is, how do I change the font in the About dialog box alone.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have added the "About" menu item via a command/menu contribution or via the "ActionFactory.ABOUT.create(window);" function then you can override the default "about" command handler by providing your own handler.

Add this to your plugin.xml:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="my.AboutActionHandler"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction">
  </handler>
```

then create the my.AboutActionHandler class:

```
package my;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;

public class AboutActionHandler extends AbstractHandler {
  @Override
  public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    new MyAboutDialog(HandlerUtil.getActiveShellChecked(event)).open();
    return null;
  }
}
```

At this point of time you really want to create the MyAboutDialog class as a subclass of the built-in AboutDialog class and simply override the `configureText` method but unfortunately the AboutDialog class is "internal" so you cannot extend it --- doh!

My recommendation is to simply open the AboutDialog class in Eclipse (shift-ctl-t AboutDialog) and copy paste the source into your own MyAboutDialog class; then just edit the `configureText` method to set the font you want. Not the most elegant option I admit but I can't see any other way.

Comment: The fix suggested by LewisG above causes the help->about menu item to be disabled.  Any suggestions on what the problem might be?